PyInstaller Error after converting py to exe but not running on other PCs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI144842\test_suite.py", line 3, in <module>
    import asyncio
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 23, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 49, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: Module use of python310.dll conflicts with this version of Python.

I got this error. Anyone who can solve this problem? It occurred when I tried to convert py into an .exe file.

what's your question? Please edit your question and add more clarity

From the Traceback, it seems that in trying to import _socket, you have an ImportError: Module use of python310.dll conflicts with this version of Python. Perhaps that module uses python 3.10 but you have 3.8.

Please show the details of how you build the exe via pyinstaller. And what's the current version of Python installed on your PC?
